# Changing before storing

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress, I want to change something in the post content before it gets stored in the database... How would I make WordPress send the content to my custom function before storing it in the database and then receive the modified content back to finally store it?

Answer (score 1):

Filter functions do exactly what you are describing.  The filter that runs prior to saving content to the database is `content_save_pre`

```
function make_all_caps($content){
    return strtoupper($content);
}

add_filter('content_save_pre','make_all_caps');
```

Add the above to your funtions.php file, or include in a plugin and it will run right before the post content is saved to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [content_save_pre](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/content_save_pre).